# jedi-vim reset docstring cache

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

Is there any way to reset the docstring preview cache that jedi-vim uses?

I have a python module that I'm working on, and none of my docstrings are accurate in the preview window when I'm outside of the module.

For example, say I have the following:

```
def foo(x):
    """Does some stuff
    :param x: the argument
    :return: the result
    :rtype: int
    """
    return x + 5

blah = foo(5)
```

When I have my cursor over foo(5) and show the docstring I get the entire docstring in the preview as expected. However, when it's imported from another file the docstring appears as it did several edits ago.

If I rename the file and import it (ie. exact same file, different module name) everything works exactly as it should.

In other words, is there some way to force jedi-vim to re-read the docstrings from a module?

Comment: That is strange, because for me it shows changes instantly. Once I update the docstring in one module, jedi-vim shows it everywhere, including other modules.

Comment: Did you maybe not save the other buffer?

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't properly show docstrings even if I make a new file and import the problem module. The only thing that makes it suddenly work is renaming the problem module.